# My computer isn't detecting a webcam at all

Tags: webcam

So, I'm trying to figure out how to get a webcam to work on my computer. The LED on the camera is turning on when I plug it in, but that's the only sign I can see of it working. When I run `ls -ltr /dev/video*` I get `ls: cannot access '/dev/video*: No such file or directory` The device doesn't seem to appear when I run `lsusb` either. As far as I can tell, my system can't even see it.